Locking rows and columns
I am quite new to coding in Excel, so I am a little troubled. But, I wanted to try and Locking Specific Columns, that can only be unlocked by respective users. And it works, HOWEVER when I tried making it so that, Specific ROWS and COLUMNS are always unlocked, it would instead UNLOCK ALL the CELLS. And I have no idea why… I coded it so that all cells are locked first, here's the code I am having trouble with:
ws.Cells.Locked = True
Debug.Print "All cells locked"
    
' Prompt for global password to unlock Rows 1-7 and Columns A-C
globalPassword = InputBox("Please enter the global password:", "Global Password Required")
If globalPassword = "GO123" Then ' Replace with the actual global password
    ' Unlock Rows 1-7 and Columns A-C
    ws.Rows("1:7").Locked = False ' Unlock Rows 1 to 7
    ws.Range("A1:C50").Locked = False ' Unlock Columns A-C in the specified range
    MsgBox "Rows 1-7 and Columns A-C are now unlocked.", vbInformation
    Debug.Print "Rows 1-7 and Columns A-C unlocked"
Else
    MsgBox "Incorrect global password. Access denied.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub ' Stop further execution if global password is wrong
End If

I tried to make it so that it would be the same as the way I did it in unlocking certain columns after a user has entered their password for their respective column. And, although it wouldn't work, since I think A1:C50 was the problem since it would keep giving errors of:

Error: Unable to set the Locked property of the Range class

So I just changed it to A1:A50 to test it out first, and thought it worked, but I guess not since it would actually UNLOCK ALL the Cells...

You need to unprotect the sheet first before the "ws.Cells.Locked = True" statement. Then at the end of the code protect the ws again.

Locked cells only behave as locked, when the sheet is protected. The cells may hold the property of locked, but if the sheet is unprotected then it is redundant until the sheet is protected again.
So for your code to remove or apply locking to cells, it needs to unprotect the sheet, change the locked property for the cells required and then finally reapply the sheet protection.
You can wrap this up in a subroutine like this:
Sub change_lock_property(rng As Range, rnglock As Boolean, pwd As String)

    With rng
        .Parent.Unprotect Password:=pwd
        .Locked = rnglock
        .Parent.Protect Password:=pwd
    End With
    
End Sub

You can then use it like so:
Sub test()

    Dim globalPassword As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    globalPassword = "the_sheet_password"
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'This locks all cells:
    change_lock_property ws.Cells, True, globalPassword
    
    'This unlocks cell A3
    change_lock_property ws.Range("A3"), False, globalPassword
    
    'This unlocks column D
    change_lock_property ws.Range("D:D"), False, globalPassword
    
    'This unlocks rows 5 to 9
    change_lock_property ws.Range("5:9"), False, globalPassword

End Sub

